# MySQLDump on Windows performance degrading over time

Tags: mysql, windows, database-performance

I have an issue that is driving me (and my customer) up the wall. They are running MySQL on Windows - I inherited this platform, I didn't design it and changing to MSSQL on Windows or migrating the MySQL instance to a *Nix VM isn't an option at this stage.

The Server is a single Windows VM, reasonably specced (4 vCores, 16 Gb RAM etc.)

Initially - they had a single Disk for the OS, MySQL and the MySQL backup location and they were getting inconsistent backups, regularly failing with the error message:

mysqldump: Got errno 22 on write

Eventually we solved this by simply moving the Backup destination to a second virtual disk (even though it is is on the same underlying Storage network, we believed that the above error was being caused by the underlying OS)

And life was good....

For about 2-3 months

Now we have a different (but my gut is telling me related) issue:

The MySQL Dump process is taking increasingly longer (over the last 4 days, the time taken for the dump has increased by about 30 mins per backup).

The Database itself is a bit large - 58 Gb, however the delta in size is only about 100 mb per day (and unless I'm missing something - it shouldn't take 30 minutes extra to dump 100 mb of Data).

Initially we thought that this was the underlying Storage network I/O - however as part of the backup script, once the .SQL file is created, it gets zipped up (to about 8.5 Gb) - and this process is very consistent in the time taken - which leads me not to suspect the disk I/O (as my presumption is that the Zip time would also increase if this were the case).

the script that I use to invoke the backup is this:

```
%mysqldumpexe% --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --single-transaction --databases %databases% --routines --force=true --max_allowed_packet=1G --triggers --log-error=%errorLogPath% > %backupfldr%FullBackup
```

the version of MySQLDump is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe

Now to compound matters - I'm primarily a Windows guy (so have limited MySQL experience) and all the Linux Guys at the office won't touch it because it's on Windows.

I suspect the cause for the increase time is that there is something funky happening with the row Locks (possibly due to the application that uses the MySQL instance) - but I'm not sure.

Now for my questions: Has anyone experienced anything similar with a gradual increase of time for a MySQL dump over time? 
Is there a way on Windows to natively monitor the performance of MySQLdump to find where the bottlenecks/locks are?
Is there a better way of doing a regular MySQL backup on a Windows platform?
Should I just tell the customer it's unsupported and to migrate it to a supported Platform?
Should I simply utter a 4 letter word and go to the Pub and drown my sorrows?

Comment: FAT32 or NTFS?  One big file?  Or multiple smaller files?  Is the dump piped to the zipper?  (Or is that really possible on Windows?)  InnoDB?  Or MyISAM?

Comment: NTFS File system
It's a Single DB that is dumped into a Single file
Dump isn't piped to the Zipper, it runs as a separate line in the batch file
DB is InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the culprit was the underlying storage network.